# Is pointcloud compressable?

Tags: ros, pr2, compressed, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the PR2 and when I'm sending the date through the network I'm having lag problems. And for example, when I receive the image of one of the cameras, there's a topic in which the information is compressed (format: `image_topic/compressed`), and this way I can speed up things. So I would like to know if it's possible to do the pointcloud generated by the kinect in a compressed format. Or in other case, is there a launch file (or something like that) in which I can take the compressed image and depth image and convert them to pointcloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167111/is-pointcloud-compressable?/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [compressed_depth_image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/compressed_depth_image_transport).

I think the Willow Garage interactive_manipulation pipeline and the oculus rift demo both make pretty heavy use of depth image compression to reduce the network bandwidth and lag problems.

You can take a look at the launch files for the PR2 Oculus Rift demo (pr2_surrogate) for an example of how to do this: https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/pr2_surrogate/tree/groovy-devel/launch

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-05-22**:
@ahendrix  the problem is not the compressed image, I can use the compressed image, but how could I generate from those images (normal image and depth image) a pointcloud image.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-12-08**:
Is your question: How to convert a depth image to a pointcloud?